# "document is not defined error" for 'document.createElement()'

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, defined

I'm using Node.js and mongodb to connect my blog database to my website. However, I keep running into both a 'window is not defined' and 'document is not defined'. It should result with images appearing in the cards that come from my database. I've tried calling that functions in different places throughout the code with no result. Can someone help?

main.js:

```js
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
var blogArray;
async function main() {
  const uri = "mongodb+srv://USERNAME:PASSWORD@cluster0-8lyed.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
  const client = new MongoClient(uri);
  try {
    await client.connect();
    await findBlogEntries(client, {
      maximumNumberOfResults: 3
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}

main().catch(console.error);

async function findBlogEntries(client, {
  maximumNumberOfResults = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
} = {}){
  const cursor = client.db("blog").collection("blog_entries").find({})
  .sort( { last_review: -1 } )
  .limit(maximumNumberOfResults);

  const results = await cursor.toArray();
  blogArray = results;
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setVals(), false);
  }

function setVals() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log("hi");
    var imgID = '#blogImage' + i;
    let img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("src", blogArray[i].image);
    img.setAttribute("class", "card-img-top");
    document.querySelector(imgID).appendChild(img);
  }
}
```

Index.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8e747eb614.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title>Daniel Palmer - Home</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
          <div class="card mb-4 shadow" style="width: 18rem;">
            <div id="blogImage0"></div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title" id="blogTitle0"></h5>
              <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted" id="blogDate0"></small></p>
              <p class="card-text" id="blogText0"></p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          <div class="card mb-4 shadow" style="width: 18rem;">
            <div id="blogImage1"></div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title" id="blogTitle1"></h5>
              <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted" id="blogDate1"></small></p>
              <p class="card-text" id="blogText1"></p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          <div class="card mb-4 shadow" style="width: 18rem;">
            <div id="blogImage2"></div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title" id="blogTitle2"></h5>
              <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted" id="blogDate2"></small></p>
              <p class="card-text" id="blogText2"></p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
<footer>
  <script src="./js/main.js" defer></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</footer>

</html>
```

Comment: You may want to see https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom

Comment: If you're running this in Node, then there is no `document` since the code doesn't work in any document context. Same thing with `window` - that's a browser thing.